# How to change $route in jest test case +VueJS +Jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-router

I am newbie to VueJS (and in test cases as well), apologize if this is already asked question,

I added a method in my component which checks the `$route.name` and returns a boolean accordingly,

BUT the issue appears in the test cases (JEST)
Have tried it with this but not working

`isAbc () {`
`return this.$route.name === 'abc-route`
`}`

This is my method for which I want to write test case,

```
const $route = {
  name: 'abc-route'
}

const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
  mocks: {
    $route
  }
})
```

I have also tried this approach
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890#issuecomment-209698782
and checked if I can get `this.$route.path` but no luck with that as well.

Anyone can please mention what am I missing or doing wrong to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anyone gets stucked on it, I have solve it by changing the approach,

Instead of assigning $router, one should do the following

```
component.vm.$router.replace({ path: '/some/path', name: 'some-name' })
```

and then test it with

```
    expect(component.vm.isAbc()).toBe(false)
```